# Keyboard pushes the whole view up in WP7

Tags: textbox, keyboard, popup, windows-phone-7.1

I have 3 grids:- Header,Body and Footer  with Body having textboxes.
I have included the Body inside a scrollviewer so that user can type as much data as he wants in the texboxes of Body.
But when the Keyboard pops up the whole view is pushed at top and I cannot see the Header.
The textboxes have wrapping on and also accepts return.
Can the scrollview move up the text when keyboard pops up?

Thanks and Regards,
Kanaya

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this will help. How about some XAML?

You could capturing the Focus event of the text box that brings the Keyboard up. In that event you could set the scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset property to some caluclated value to get whatever you want in view.

Edit: HorizontalOffest is only a getter user [ScrollToHorizontalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltohorizontaloffset%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead

Comment: Nopes. scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset property is a readonly(Get) property so cannot assign any values.

Comment: Updated answer to include ScrollToHorizontalOffset instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably *can* make it scroll up like you want, but it will appear very strange to seasoned users of the WP7 operating system. Expected behavior for text input is exactly what you described, the notion Microsoft (I *believe*) is trying to hit here is that when you want to type something in, you want to clear everything else out of view, and only focus on the textbox at hand.